# extract strings out of plist with bash script, maybe sed?

Tags: bash, sed, plist

So here is my problem.
How can I extract those strings into 3 variables with a bash script?

So out of this:

```
<key>GameDir</key> <string>C:/Program Files/</string> <key>GameEXE</key> <string>C:/Program Files/any.exe</string> <key>GameFlags</key> <string>-anyflag</string>
```

I want:

```
GameDir=C:/Program Files/
GameEXE=C:/Program Files/any.exe
GameFlags=-anyflag
```

Example Script:

```
echo GameDir
echo GameEXE
echo GameFlags
```

Example Output:

```
C:/Program Files/
C:/Program Files/any.exe
-anyflag
```

The order of the keys is not changing, only the strings itself.
I am using OS X, so it needs to be a command that works out-of-the-box on OS X.
Maybe this could work with sed?

Thanks
Drakulix

Answer (score 8):

You could use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` for this, which seems to be included in OS X since at least 10.5 ([man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.5/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html)). Example:

```
file="$HOME/yourfile"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print" "$file"
```

And you could assign the vars you're interested in like this:

```
for var in GameDir GameEXE GameFlags ; do
    val=$( /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print $var" "$file" )
    eval "export $var='$val'"
    echo "$var = $val"
done
```

It seems more readable than bash/sed/awk regexes, and since it is a plist-specific tool, I presume it is reliable for extracting values. Just be aware that the keys are case-sensitive.

Comment: I might replace the `eval` with `declare -x $var="$val"`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Bash version >= 3.2

```
string='<key>GameDir</key> <string>C:/Program Files/</string> <key>GameEXE</key> <string>C:/Program Files/any.exe</string> <key>GameFlags</key> <string>-anyflag</string>'
```

or

```
string=$(<file)
```

and

```
pattern='<key>([^<]*)</key>[[:blank:]]*<string>([^<]*)</string>[[:blank:]]*'
pattern=$pattern$pattern$pattern
[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]    # extract the matches into ${BASH_REMATCH[@]}
for ((i=1; i<${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}; i+=2))
do
    declare ${BASH_REMATCH[i]}="${BASH_REMATCH[i+1]}"    # make the assignments
done
echo $GameDir    # these were missing dollar signs in your question
echo $GameEXE
echo $GameFlags
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk, this works for multiline and multiple key, string values.

```
$ cat file
<key>GameDir</key> <string>C:/Program Files/
   </string>
<key>GameEXE</key>
  <string>C:/Program Files/any.exe
 </string> <key>GameFlags</key> <string>-anyflag</string>

$ awk -vRS="</string>" '/<key>/{gsub(/<key>|<string>|\n| +/,"") ; sub("</key>","=") ;print}' file
GameDir=C:/ProgramFiles/
GameEXE=C:/ProgramFiles/any.exe
GameFlags=-anyflag
```

Use eval to create the variables

```
$ eval $(awk -vRS="</string>" '/<key>/{gsub(/<key>|<string>|\n| +/,"") ; sub("</key>","=") ;print}' file )
$ echo $GameDir
C:/ProgramFiles/
```